# Is it possible to slice an inner matrix with brackets?

Tags: go, matrix, slice

I am modifying the perimeter values on a matrix, then trying to recurse into the inner values. I expected I'd be able to access the inner values with something like `matrix[1:3][1:3]`. This is not the case, and I'm a bit lost as to the underlying logic of how Go handles sequential brackets.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var m = [][]int{
    []int{0, 1, 2, 3},
    []int{4, 5, 6, 7},
    []int{8, 9, 10, 11},
    []int{12, 13, 14, 15},
}
```

I am trying to access the values 5, 6, 9, 10 in the above matrix -- the "inner" matrix.

```
func main() {
    inner := m[1:3][1:3]
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", inner)
    // Expected Output: [][]int{
    // []int{5, 6},
    // []int{9, 10}
    // }
    // Actual Ouput: [][]int{
    // []int{8, 9, 10, 11},
    // []int{12, 13, 14, 15}
    // }
    inner = m[1:3]
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", inner)
    // Output:
    // [][]int{
    // []int{4, 5, 6, 7},
    // []int{8, 9, 10, 11}
    // }
    inner = innerMatrix(m)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", inner)
    // [][]int{
    // []int{5, 6},
    // []int{9, 10}
}

func innerMatrix(m [][]int) (inner [][]int) {
    innerRows := m[1:3]
    for _, row := range innerRows {
        inner = append(inner, row[1:3])
    }
    return
}
```

The function innerMatrix is able to produce the output I expected. I'm lost as to why (1) `m[1:3][1:3]` doesn't have the same effect, (2) it seems to translate to `m[2:4]`. What's going on?

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xjZXA1PE9S5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a sub-slice in Go, you're allowed to grow that sub-slice back to the capacity of the original slice again, e.g.:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

    b := a[1:3]
    fmt.Printf("a[1:3]: %v\n", b)

    c := b[1:3]
    fmt.Printf("b[1:3]: %v\n", c)
}
```

which outputs:

```
a[1:3]: [2 3]
b[1:3]: [3 4]
```

Note that `b` only has two elements, but we're allowed to create a slice of the second and third elements because the capacity of the slice it's a sub-slice of is sufficiently large, and all the slices share the same underlying array. See the last example in section "Slice internals" on [this page](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

So what's happening in your case is that `m[1:3]` is equivalent to:

```
var m1 = [][]int{
    []int{4, 5, 6, 7},   // second element of m
    []int{8, 9, 10, 11}, // third element of m
}
```

and `m[1:3][1:3]` is therefore equivalent to `m1[1:3]`, which is equivalent to:

```
var m2 = [][]int{
    []int{8, 9, 10, 11},   // second element of m1
    []int{12, 13, 14, 15}, // "third" element of m1
}
```

with the "third" element appearing only because the capacity of `m` is large enough to contain it, and does in fact contain it. If `m` only had three elements, this would cause a panic.

In other words, `m[1:3][1:3]` is here exactly equivalent to `m[2:4]`, because `m[1:3][1:3]` gives you the second and third elements of `m[1:3]`. Maybe easier to understand with a diagram:

```
m            : []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
m[1:3]       : []int{   2, 3   }
m[1:3][1:3]  : []int{      3, 4}
m[2:4]       : []int{      3, 4}
```

As an oversimplification, you can imagine that the square brackets give the requested elements of whatever is immediately to the left of them, so a somewhat extreme example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

    b := a[1:5]
    fmt.Printf("b: %v, a[1:5]               : %v\n",
        b, a[1:5])

    c := b[1:4]
    fmt.Printf("c: %v  , a[1:5][1:4]          : %v\n",
        c, a[1:5][1:4])

    d := c[1:3]
    fmt.Printf("d: %v    , a[1:5][1:4][1:3]     : %v\n",
        d, a[1:5][1:4][1:3])

    e := d[1:2]
    fmt.Printf("e: %v      , a[1:5][1:4][1:3][1:2]: %v\n",
        e, a[1:5][1:4][1:3][1:2])
}
```

which outputs:

```
b: [2 3 4 5], a[1:5]               : [2 3 4 5]
c: [3 4 5]  , a[1:5][1:4]          : [3 4 5]
d: [4 5]    , a[1:5][1:4][1:3]     : [4 5]
e: [5]      , a[1:5][1:4][1:3][1:2]: [5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your data:

```
var m = [][]int{
    []int{0, 1, 2, 3},
    []int{4, 5, 6, 7},
    []int{8, 9, 10, 11},
    []int{12, 13, 14, 15},
}
```

First you ask what is inner := m[1:3][1:3]?

Well, taking one at a time, m[1:3] is the subslice you get when grabbing elements 1 to 3 not including 3.  So that is elements 1 and 2.  Element 0 is []int{0, 1, 2, 3}, element 1 is []int{4, 5, 6, 7}, and element 2 is []int{8, 9, 10, 11},

So m[1:3] is

```
[][]int{
    []int{4, 5, 6, 7},
    []int{8, 9, 10, 11},
}
```

Now, to get m[1:3][1:3] we repeat the same thing on this result.
However, this time, there are only two elements.  We again want elements 1 and 2.  We skip element 0 which is []int{4, 5, 6, 7}.  Element 1 is []int{8, 9, 10, 11}.  There is no element 2.  However, the result of m[1:3] was a subslice and the underlying slice had an additional element.
So by extending this subslice we can get that element back again, and that is the hiddent element 2 which is []int{12, 13, 14, 15}.
So m[1:3][1:3] is

```
[][]int{
    []int{8, 9, 10, 11},
    [[]int{12, 13, 14, 15},
}
```

Finally, you wonder why func innerMatrix works differently?    It starts by producing m[1:3] which is

```
[][]int{
    []int{4, 5, 6, 7},
    []int{8, 9, 10, 11},
}
```

**Then the code IS NOT taking another subslice in the same way that m[1:3][1:3] is two consecutive subslices.  Instead, you take each element in the slice and grab the subslice from each element.**  The first time through you grab subslices [1:3] from []int{4, 5, 6, 7}.  The result of that is

```
[]int{5, 6}
```

The second time through you do the same on the second element []int{8, 9, 10, 11} which is

```
[]int{9, 10}
```

Finally, each time through you append the result to the result slice, so you append []int{5, 6} to [], to give [][]{int{5, 6}}, and then you append []int{9, 10}  to give

```
[][]{int{5, 6}, []int{9, 10} }
```